# コンテナの中で iotop を実行すると OSError: Netlink error: No such file or director が出る

Tags: ubuntu, docker, monitoring

Docker の `ubuntu:18.04` にインストールした iotop コマンドを実行すると `OSError: Netlink error` が起きます。どうすれば正常に起動できるでしょうか？

以下エラー全文です。

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/iotop", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 620, in main
    main_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 610, in <lambda>
    main_loop = lambda: run_iotop(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 508, in run_iotop
    return curses.wrapper(run_iotop_window, options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/curses/__init__.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 498, in run_iotop_window
    taskstats_connection = TaskStatsNetlink(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/iotop/data.py", line 137, in __init__
    self.family_id = controller.get_family_id('TASKSTATS')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/iotop/genetlink.py", line 69, in get_family_id
    m = GeNlMessage.recv(self.conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/iotop/genetlink.py", line 51, in recv
    msg = conn.recv()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/iotop/netlink.py", line 229, in recv
    raise err
OSError: Netlink error: No such file or directory (2)
```

再現手順

```sh
$ docker run -it --rm ubuntu:18.04
root@618d29523b07:/# apt update
（省略）
root@618d29523b07:/# apt install iotop
（省略）
root@618d29523b07:/# iotop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/iotop", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 620, in main
    main_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 610, in <lambda>
    main_loop = lambda: run_iotop(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 508, in run_iotop
    return curses.wrapper(run_iotop_window, options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/curses/__init__.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 498, in run_iotop_window
    taskstats_connection = TaskStatsNetlink(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/iotop/data.py", line 137, in __init__
    self.family_id = controller.get_family_id('TASKSTATS')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/iotop/genetlink.py", line 69, in get_family_id
    m = GeNlMessage.recv(self.conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/iotop/genetlink.py", line 51, in recv
    msg = conn.recv()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/iotop/netlink.py", line 229, in recv
    raise err
OSError: Netlink error: No such file or directory (2)
root@618d29523b07:/#
```

環境

- `iotop --version`: `iotop 0.6`
- Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
- ホスト環境: macOS Mojave